# Can differential forms dissipate?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a closed manifold. Is there a non-zero differential form $ \omega$ on $M$ and an isotopy $ \phi_t$: $ t \in [0, \infty)$ so that $ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \phi_t^\ast \omega = 0 $? That is, so that $ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty } \| \phi_t^\ast \omega \|_{\sup} = 0$ where the norm is defined below. Equivalently I'm asking if the orbits of the natural action of the group of isotopies of $M$ on the space $ \Omega^k (M)$ of $k$-forms  ever accumulate on $0$, where $ \Omega^k (M)$ is equipped with the sup-norm topology.

Definition of Sup-Norm: Equip the manifold $M$ with a Riemannian metric $g$, which then extends to the exterior algebra of the cotangent bundle(declare the natural basis of wedge products of an orthonormal basis of $T^\ast M$ to be orthonormal, this turns out to be independent of the chosen orthonormal basis). Then defining $ \| \omega \|_{\sup}  = \sup_{x \in M} \| \omega_x \|= g( \omega_x, \omega_x)^{1/2}$ gives a norm to the space of forms $ \Omega^k (M)$(for functions consider the standard sup-norm). We have uniform convergence  $\omega_t \rightarrow \omega $ when $ \| \omega_t - \omega\|_{\sup} \rightarrow 0$.

Some classes of examples where this fails: Suppose that $ \omega$ is closed but not exact. Thus we have a cycle $ \sigma $ on which the integral $ \int_\sigma \omega $ is non-zero. Then $ \int_{\sigma} \phi_t^\ast \omega = \int_{\phi_t( \sigma)} \omega = \int_{\sigma } \omega$ since $ \phi_t ( \sigma) $ and $\sigma $ are homotopic. As the map $ \alpha \mapsto \int_\sigma \alpha$ is continuous with respect to the norm $ \| \cdot \|_\sup$, we can't have $ \| \phi_t^\ast \omega \|_\sup \rightarrow 0$.

Consider $ \omega = df$ for some function $f$. Then $ \phi_t^\ast f=f_t $ will have (non-unique) minimum and maximum $m_t$ and $M_t$, respectively. Integrating $df$ along the shortest geodesic $ \gamma$ yields the same number  $f_t(M_t)-f_t(m_t) = \int_{\gamma} df_t \leq length(\gamma) \| df_t \|_\sup \leq diam(M) \| df_t \|_\sup $. So no dissipation here either.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking: You already know that this is not true for all differential forms. Are you asking about examples of (nonzero) differential forms which can dissipate? Then it is of course possible (even for functions on the circle): This is something one typically learns in a real analysis class when discussing the difference between pointwise convergence and, say, $L^1$-convergence.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment. I edited my question accordingly. I initially considered pointwise convergence, but in that case one can trivially make a form dissipate, even volume forms. So that is replaced with uniform convergence now.

Comment: How do you define uniform convergence of differential forms? This should be a part of your post. (I have my definition but it might not agree with yours.)